# why get error element recordcount is undefined?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a query

```
SELECT csedept_name,submitterdept, COUNT(execoffice_status) as 'starsgiven'
FROM   Depts d 
       LEFT JOIN CSEReduxResponses c on d.csedept_id = c.submitterdept
                                    .......
                                    and YEAR ([approveddate]) =2014
                                    and month ([approveddate]) =12
                                    ....
```

and when i run in on the microsolf sql server studio i get 
20 rows return and all with 'submitterdept' null.
but I keep getting this error:

```
Element RECORDCOUNT is undefined in GETBRANCHSTARS.

The error occurred in stars.cfm: line 498

496 : </cfif>
497 : <cfset totalbranch =0 >
498 : <cfif getbranchstars.recordcount gt 0>
499 : 
500 :   <h1> Counts </h1
```

For some reason is not recognizing recordcount.

What im I doing wrong?

```
<cfset totalbranch =0 >

<cfif getbranchstars.recordcount gt 0>  
    <table >
        <thead><tr><th>Branch</th><th>Stars Given</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
        <cfoutput query="getbranchstars" >
        <tr>
        <td>#CSEDEPT_NAME#</td>
        <td>#BRANCHTOTALSTARSGIVEN#</td>
        </tr>
        <cfset totalbranch += BRANCHTOTALSTARSGIVEN>
        </cfoutput>
        </tbody>

     <tfoot>
        <cfoutput>
        <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th><div align="left">#totalbranch#</div></th>
        </tr>
        </cfoutput>
    </tfoot>

    </table>

<cfelse>
<p>No Branch Department Counts</p>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Please add in your cfquery tag or new query() method to your example... the issue is likely there

Comment: Agreed, show more code.  Also, check for any conditional statements around the query that might be preventing it from running in certain conditions which would mean the getbranchstars query variable might not even be defined.

Comment: i see what i can do , the thing is if i change the month in query to 11 it works great

Comment: Two things. One, what @ChrisTierney is asking for is literally the `<cfquery..>` line, or if you create this with cfscript, provide that. And he's right. Two, as to changing the month fixing it, it's hard to imagine a scenario where that alone is the cause.

Comment: Did you at least dump out `GETBRANCHSTARS` (very poor name for a variable, btw: that's more like the name of a function) to see what *was* in it?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when running a routine that switches a session-scoped setting at the application onRequest, that impacted conditional logic as to whether to run the query or not. When the session-scoped setting is set to do the query, the later code gets run based on that session-scoped setting to output the data if RECORDCOUNT. Upon subsequent calls to the same page without the switching, the page runs fine. So apparently CF somehow was getting the new session setting in time to run the query but not in time to run all the housekeeping to attach recordCount to the query object. I took out the session-scoped condition whether to run the query and I am no longer getting the missing RECORDCOUNT error.

Answer (score -1):

I have also gotten that error. In my case I solved the problem by adding the result parameter to cfquery, `result="result_name"`. Then changed `query_name.recordcount` to `result_name.recordcount`.